# oil level on dipstick

Tags: engine, oil, small-engine, oil-pan

Which way should this dipstick be placed? When placed in with the bend facing towards the engine it gives a different reading from when placed facing the opposite way. There is not a great deal of difference between the readings so I do not believe that it matters greatly just wondering if anyone knows.

The car is a 1.25 Duratec ford fiesta if it matters

The difference in the readings is about 1/3 of the distance between the min and max.

(pointless question I know I am just curious)

[image]

Comment: Actually, one-third of the difference between min and max is potentially quite large. Imagine if you are at max level one way but one-third over with the dipstick facing the other way. Great question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a level difference equivalent to one-third of the difference between min and max is quite large.

This tells me that the dipstick is not fully seated in the dipstick channel in one of the orientations.

I would consider the orientation in which the dipstick rests lower in the channel (resulting in a higher level reading) to be the correct one to use.